# Extract the bottom 32-bit element from an AVX-512 vector

Tags: c, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx512

Is there something less awkward than this to get the least significant element from an `__m512i`?

```
int extract_bottom {
    return _mm256_extract_epi32(_mm512_castsi512_si256(v), 0);
}
```

Comment: Is there no cast from `__m512i` straight to `__m128i` so you could use a normal `_mm_cvt???` whatever they call `movd`?  (I have to look it every damn time; the naming is so non-obvious and non-memorable I find.)

Comment: Oh yeah, there is, I guess that's technically better especially if the compiler is dumb (in practice even the above ends up with `movd`). [Like this](https://godbolt.org/z/3-Eboh).

Comment: Yeah, compilers are generally fine at optimizing away `extract(v, 0)`.  I tend to like to write intrinsics that match how I intend it to compile, just because that's how I'm thinking of it anyway.  Especially for floating point where there is no instruction needed, just a reinterpret, but also for integer.

Comment: The problem was I was looking for the equivalent of `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` in i256 but of course that doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't think you can do "less awkward" than your `foo` function in https://godbolt.org/z/3-Eboh (you can of course wrap that into an inline function with a better name).